# How to set and print default value of a variable in awk

Tags: awk

How to set a default value of a variable if the variable remain unset, below are the details

Like in bash :

```
x=1
echo ${x}
1
unset x
echo "${x:-I AM DEFAULT}"
```

How can this behavior achieved in awk:

Example:

```
 -->echo "$x"
one two three four
foo bla2 bla3 bla4
bar bla7 bla8
```

Desired result:

```
echo "$x" |awk '..'
bla2 bla3 bla4 bla7 NA bla8
```

Current output:

```
echo "$x" |awk '/foo/{two=$2;three=$3;four=$4;next} /bar/{print two , three, four, $2,$3,$4} '
bla2 bla3 bla4 bla7 bla8
```

Cannot do like: (stupid act due to desperation) :

```
echo "$x" |awk '/foo/{two=$2;three=$3;four=$4;next} /bar/{print two , three, four, $2,${3:-NA},$4} '
```

OR

for awk `$3` is bla8 so this will also not work.

```
echo "$x" |awk '/foo/{two=$2;three=$3;four=$4;next} /bar/{if(!length($3))print two , three, four, $2,$3,"NA",$4;print two , three, four, $2,$3,$4} '
bla2 bla3 bla4 bla7 bla8
```

Comment: Do you simply want `awk 'NR > 1 { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, FS; print "" }'`?  That does output a final field separator, but that can be tweaked if it matters.  And you can track the number of fields in the first line and make sure that many entries are output if that's what's required.  And if the count is short, you can output `NA` at any position you choose.  The key idea is using `$i` to access fields by number (and using NF to identify the number of fields on the line, and maybe using NR (or FNR) to identify the record number (in the current file).

Comment: why is "NA" not the last field and instead between bla7 and bla8?  The output should be "bla2 bla3 bla4 bla7 bla8 NA" which is doable.

Comment: I believe you are misinterpreting the concept of `awk`. Why do you believe that awk can detect that field 3 is missing. There is no distinct difference between processing `foo bla2 bla3 bla4` and `bar bla7 bla8` except that the former has 4 fields and the latter 3. awk does not know anything about missing fields. And if it does, how would it know that the missing field is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. An empty field could be detected, if and only if you define a good field separator `FS`. Then you might write stuff as `($3==""?"NA":$3)`

Comment: Thanks, I was not clear what I was asking. I think I understand the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you wouldn't know any mid value missing, since fields will just shift to left.  There are two approaches you can take, either from number of fields `NF` set the missing values.  Or, use some null value substitute.  Here is a sample of the latter:

```
$ awk 'function nvl(x) {return x==""?"NA":x} {print nvl($1), nvl($2), nvl($3)}'


$ echo a b | awk ...
a b NA

$ echo a | awk ...
a NA NA

$ echo "" | awk ...
NA NA NA
```

Comment: good answer, but in the OP `echo a b` should return `a NA b`. There is no way you can do this, unless you define `FS` as a single space, and have two spaces between `a` and `b`.

Comment: I was unclear in asking question, but you addressed it right. Thank you.

Comment: but awk has its own variables, could be better to use that one instead of the shell one. `awk '{...}' var="$value1" input_file`